# Modifiying imported shapes in OpenSCAD

Tags: openscad, stl-format

Given an STL file, OpenSCAD is able to import it:

```
import("file.stl");
```

I can also transform the result.  However, when I try to do any openscad commands, the imported shape disappears:

```
translate([10,0,0])
    import("Boat.stl");
cube(5);
```

Once the function call is added to any native shape, the boat disappears.  Is there any way around this?  I am trying to take a shape that has been sliced into pieces in netfabb, and create tabs so the the pieces fit precisely together for gluing.

Comment: Have you looked at the [documentation](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/STL_Import_and_Export)?

Comment: Also check the FAQ: "[Why is my imported STL file only showing up with F5 but not F6?](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/FAQ#Why_is_my_imported_STL_file_only_showing_up_with_F5_but_not_F6.3F)"